# collaborative canvas with angular and firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, google-cloud-firestore, fabricjs

I am trying to create a real time collaborative canvas on ionic/angular+fabric.js+firestore. I have the canvas, I serialize it to json, store it (and update it from different users) but I do not get to refresh every user's canvases. How can I accomplish this?

First of all, I get connected to the collection:

```
this.imageCollection = database.collection<MyImage>("images");
this.drawing = this.imageCollection.doc(this.chatId).valueChanges();
this.writeCanvas();
```

Then, I have this function that is called on every "mouse up":

```
loadOnCanvas(){
    var json = JSON.stringify(this.f_canvas);
    this.us.addCanvastoDB(json, this.chatId);
    this. writeCanvas();
   }
```

And the following function is where I am trying to write to the shared canvas (that is not actually shared) because it doesn't get updated with different users' drawings. This function is called at the begining of the class (`ngOnInit`) and after each `loadOnCanvas` (see above):

```
writeCanvas(){
    let that = this;
    this.drawing.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data=>{
      that.read_json = data[0]['canvas'];
      if(that.read_json){
        this.f_canvas.clear();
        console.log("data loaded", that.read_json);
      that.f_canvas.loadFromJSON(that.read_json, that.f_canvas.renderAll.bind(that.f_canvas));
      }
    });
```

The data from the firestore is saved in the database when I start drawing but if another user (or same user after having left the app) enters again an empty canvas is displayed and the data from the database is not loaded.

This is the function that stores the data in the database. It is in a service:

```
addCanvastoDB(canvas: any, chatId:string) {
    //Create an ID for document
    const id = this.database.createId();
    console.log("chat id: ", chatId);
    //Set document id with value in database
    this.imageCollection
      .doc(chatId)
      .set({canvas: canvas, chatid: chatId},
        { merge: true })
      .then(resp => {
        console.log("resp", resp);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error " + error);
      });
  }
```

And this is all the relevant code from my component:

```
    export class DrawComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() chatId: string;
  @Input() typeOfImg: string;
  @Input() userId: string;

  @Output() passEntry: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 @ViewChild('my_canvas', {static: false}) my_canvas: ElementRef;

  images: Observable<MyImage[]>;
  private imageCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<MyImage>;

  private f_canvas:any;
  private read_json: any;
  drawing: any;

  constructor(
     public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
    public cs: ChatService,
    public us: UploadService,
    private modalController: ModalController,
    private database: AngularFirestore,
    public events: Events,

  ) {
    this.availableColours = ["#dd0000", "#000000", "#00dd00", "#ffdd00"];
    //Set collection where our documents/ images info will save
    this.imageCollection = database.collection("images");  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.f_canvas = new fabric.Canvas('my_canvas', {selection: true});
    this.f_canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    this.f_canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    this.f_canvas.selection = true;
    this.currentColour = '#000000';
    this.f_canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 3; // size of the drawing brush
    this.tool_selected = "selection_tool";
    this.background_visible = false;
    this.load_background();
    let that = this;
    this.f_canvas.on("mouse:down", function(o) {
      that.mousedown(o);
    });
    this.f_canvas.on("mouse:move", function(e) {
      that.mousemove(e);
    });
    this.f_canvas.on("mouse:up", function(e) {
      that.mouseup(e);
    });
    console.log("chatid en draw", this.chatId);
    this.drawing = this.imageCollection.doc(this.chatId).valueChanges();
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this. writeCanvas();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){

  }
  //save canvas in firestore
  loadOnCanvas(){
    var json = JSON.stringify(this.f_canvas);
    console.log("chat id sent to store canvas");
    this.us.addCanvastoDB(json, this.chatId);
    this. writeCanvas();
   }
//draw the canvas with the data from firestore  
   writeCanvas(){
    let that = this;
    console.log("writing canvas");
      this.drawing.pipe(tap(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        if(data[0]['canvas']){
          that.read_json = data[0]['canvas'];
          if(that.read_json){
            this.f_canvas.clear();
            console.log("data loaded", that.read_json);
          that.f_canvas.loadFromJSON(that.read_json, that.f_canvas.renderAll.bind(that.f_canvas));
          }
        }
      }));
   }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Are the canvas updates being pushed to Firestore correctly? i.e: If a user changes the canvas are the changes serialized and visible from Firestore page? If that's the case the error probably lies in the rendering side and not in the database side.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. Yes, the JSON from the canvas is stored and updated correctly from different users but somehow the canvas is neither loaded nor refreshed  in diferente users. Meaning that when a second user enters the canvas, the already existing canvas doesn't even get loaded. That second user can draw and the data is updated but no canvases are being updated.

Comment: What do you mean by " when a second user enters the canvas, the already existing canvas doesn't even get loaded"? Is it displaying a new empty canvas? It may be you're not referencing the same document. Also, why you call `const id = this.database.createId();`? and why you update the chatId when writing the canvas to firestore? Shouldn't it be a static Id shared by all the users that interact with the same canvas?

Comment: hi and thanks for the tip again! Sorry about that line about `createId` because it was from a previous test and I forgot to delete it before posting it.

Comment: Following your tip anyway I realized that the problem is that I am trying to draw on the canvas _before_ I have got the values of the JSON data. You were right, what I meant is that when I open the drawing component it displays an empty canvas even if there is data loaded from `revious drawings. Do you have any hint for me? I am quite new to firestore and this asynchronous way of working with javascript...

Comment: I have updated the question with the whole code to see if it is clearer

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly why but I got this working when I changed the way I was reading from the database. Instead of using `tap` I am using `take(1)`. The new block is like this:

```
this.drawing.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data=>{
  //OLD WAY: this.drawing.pipe(tap(data=>{

    if(data.canvas){
      that.read_json = data.canvas;
      if(that.read_json){
        this.f_canvas.clear();
      that.f_canvas.loadFromJSON(that.read_json, that.f_canvas.renderAll.bind(that.f_canvas));
      }
    }
  });
```

Thanks a lot for the help anyway!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why this worked as I never worked with pipe() and tap() before. Nonetheless I have found this links which may be of some help to understand why https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap and https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators . I suspect that the interaction of pipe and tap was not behaving as you expected. Glad to know you solved the issue.